# What is the fastest way to read large data from multiple files and aggregate data in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have many files: 1.csv, 2.csv ... N.csv.  I want to read them all and aggregate a DataFrame. But reading files sequentially in one process will definitely be slow. So how can I improve it? Besides, Jupyter notebook is used.

Also, I am a little confused about the "cost of parsing parameters or return values between python processes"

I know the question may be duplicated. But I found that most of the answers use multi-process to solve it. Multiprocess does solve the `GIL` problem. But in my experience(maybe it is wrong): parsing large data(like a DataFrame) as a parameter to subprocess is slower than a for loop in a single process because the procedure needs serializing and de-serializing. And I am not sure about the return of large values from the subprocess.

Is it most efficient to use a `Qeueu` or `joblib` or `Ray`?

Comment: I think none of those will really help you if you need a single dataframe as output. You'll be spending a lot of time concatenating the data in the final process.

Comment: I just need a list, like [df1, ... dfN] or [[row11, row12, .. row1M] ... [rowN1...rowNM]], then the cost of pd.concat is inevitable and is not the concern of the post.

Comment: If all the CSV files are homogeneous, why not just `cat` them together and read the single file? (Or read from a `cat *.csv` pipe.)

Comment: So read a `cat *.csv` from single process will be faster than read from multiple process and concat them?

Comment: You would have to measure it, wouldn't you?

Comment: impossible to say without knowing what the bottleneck is.  How many csv files, how big are they. Are you just optimizing load time?

Answer (score 0):

Reading csv is fast. I would read all csv in a list and then concat the list to one dataframe. Here is a bit of code form my use case. I find all .csv files in my path and save the csv file names in variable "results". I then loop the file names and read the csv and store it in list which I later concat to one dataframe.

```
data = []
for item in result:
   data.append(pd.read_csv(path))
main_df = pd.concat(data, axis = 0)
```

I am not saying this is the best approach, but this works great for me :)